# Is there a way to pass down a variable in an Autowired Constructor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, autowired

To keep it as simple as Possible I have a class which I want to open threw another class. It needs some Services to be Autowired plus, because it is a Review view, it also needs a Variable of the movie passed down to it so that the Review can be saved there. But every time I try to ad in a Movie class as constructor variable it says, the class is not Autowirable.

```
@PageTitle("GiveReview")
@Route(value = "givereview",layout = MainLayout.class)
@PermitAll
public class GiveReviewView extends Div {

private final AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser;
private final ReviewService reviewService;
private final MovieService movieService;

private Movie movie;
@Autowired
public GiveReviewView(AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser, ReviewService reviewService, MovieService movieService) {
    this.authenticatedUser = authenticatedUser;
    this.reviewService = reviewService;
    this.movieService = movieService;

}
```

when I add (Movie movie) inside of the constructor I get an error

Comment: To be able to pass a movie in GiveReviewView you need to have already created bean of this type.

Comment: I have a Movie class, but if I make the Movie a Bean, doesnt that mean that it is just one Movie that can be initialized ? I have a List of movies so when I click on one, I want to go to reviews with that spezific Movie

Comment: in that case, I wouldn`t set the movie as part of construction,but as part of a method argument or if you plan to use it in multiple methods by a set method because you need to be able to change it depends of the film .

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a X-Y-problem. Injecting some concrete data in your route c'tor
is the wrong approach (and I think, it's not even possible, but some Spring
guru surely will prove me wrong).  Inject all the things the view/route needs
to do its work and then parameterize loading/showing the movie to work on it.

How to do that, you can find here
https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-router-url-parameters

```java
@Route(value = "movie/rate")
public class MovieRatingView extends Div implements HasUrlParameter<Long> {
    @Override
    public void setParameter(BeforeEvent event, Long movieId) {
        // load movie, redirect if not found or show error
    }
}
```

v23 allows even more influence, where in the path, your values can come from.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, but how does the Method know wich variable to take from the previous event and bring it with onto the next page ?

Comment: You pass the id with the `navigateTo` method from `UI`.